# How can I get the index of second comma?

Tags: c#, .net, string, indexof

```
        //read
        Console.Write("Please enter (pyramid slot number,block letter,whether or not the block should be lit): ");
        string csvString = Console.ReadLine();

        //location of comma
        int firstComma = csvString.IndexOf(',');
        int secondComma = csvString.IndexOf(',', firstComma + 1);

        //extract slot number of pyramid
        int slotNumber = int.Parse(csvString.Substring(0, firstComma));
        string blockLetter = csvString.Substring(firstComma + 1, secondComma);
        Boolean lit = Boolean.Parse(csvString.Substring(secondComma + 1));

        //print
        Console.WriteLine("Pyramid Slot Number: " + slotNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Block Letter: " + blockLetter);
        Console.WriteLine("Lit: " + lit);
```

I tried to input like "5,M,true". However output for Block Letter is "M,t". If I try to input 15 instead of 5, then it gives "M,tr". In the end, I want to get only one letter. I'll use char after I figure this problem out.

Edit:
`char blockLetter = char.Parse(csvString.Substring(firstComma + 1, 1));`
I used this thank you!

Comment: I think the bug in your code is the use of Substring method, which should be passed (index, length), while you pass (index, other_index). You would need to pass (index, other_index - index) instead.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of [`String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is the start index, the second parameter is not the end index but the length. So you need to calculate it:

```
int firstComma = csvString.IndexOf(',');
int startIndex = firstComma + 1;
int secondComma = csvString.IndexOf(',', startIndex);
int length = secondComma - startIndex;
string blockLetter = csvString.Substring(startIndex, length);
```

An easier way is to use `String.Split` to get a `string[]` with all tokens delimited by comma:

```
string[] allSlots = csvString.Split(',');
// first token is in allSlots[0] and second in allSlots[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, based on code provided, you want the values delimited by commas. If I guessed correctly, then better use [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) method.

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV file contains the data you anyway read, you could just split the string on comma and then extract individual fields by indices. Here is an example:

```
var csvEntry = "5,M,true";
var entryData = csvEntry.Split(',');

var slotNumber = int.Parse(entryData[0]);
var blockLetter = entryData[1];
var lit = bool.Parse(entryData[2]);

Console.WriteLine($"Pyramid Slot Number: {slotNumber}");
Console.WriteLine($"Block Letter: {blockLetter}");
Console.WriteLine($"Lit: {lit}");
```